# ASPDotNetStoreFront and PayPal Express: order details are not displayed when client is redirected to PayPal

Tags: paypal, aspdotnetstorefront

I enabled the PayPal Express payment in ASPDotNetStoreFront, and when the client gets redirected to PayPal the following message appears in the order summary area, instead of the order items and total:

You'll be able to see your order details before you pay.

I found out that this has to do with the request that is being sent by ASPDotNetStoreFront, so my question is: can ASPDotNetStoreFront be configured so that it sends the corresponding request to PayPal, in order for PayPal to display the order summary?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The PayPal Express integration in AspDotNetStorefront does not include this information, correct. We hope to change that in a future release.

A custom fix should be possible to develop for this issue. We recommend one of our Development Partners as they are knowledgeable and experienced with our software:

http://www.aspdotnetstorefront.com/c-121-development-partners.aspx

PayPal Standard does contain order summary information.

AspDotNetStorefront Support